# Run a simple http server locally on a non-80 port

Tags: webserver, http

I have access to a Linux server with a non-root user. What I need is to run a simple, HTTP server that will not listen to port 80, but to a different port.

I'm looking for the most easiest and quickest solution. Don't need any authentication or whatever.

Would be also nice to run it in a SCREEN.

Linux version is Red Hat 4.1.2-50

Comment: What exactly is the purpose, just serving some static pages?

Comment: Actually serving static files via http. lighttpd did the job.

Comment: "Would be also nice to run it in a SCREEN" - eh? It's a daemon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is quite subjective, and configuring the port should be very easy with any http server.

Though, I would recommend `lighttpd` with `server.port = 1080` (or whatever above 1024 for non-root users) in a configuration file:

```
server.document-root = "/home/foo/www" 
server.port = 1080
```

It's a complete enough http server, and for serving static contents, almost no other configuration is needed. Just put your data in the `server.document-root` directory, and start it with `lighttpd -f configuration-file`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it could be easier but I managed at the end :)

Comment: @yellowblood Btw, if you want to see the log in your `screen`, there's a `-D` option to prevent daemon mode.

Comment: Yea, I know that ;)

Answer (score 1):

On higher ports you usually don't need any elevated permissions. Give [lighttp](http://www.lighttpd.net/) or [thttpd](http://acme.com/software/thttpd/) a try. Best point to start would be the [FAQ](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/lighttpd/FrequentlyAskedQuestions), the other Docs are linked from there. If your admin does not have installed any webservers you like, you can [dowload and build the source](http://www.lighttpd.net/download).

Answer (score 0):

*mini_httpd** is also a good, small HTTP server. You can configure port in mini_httpd.conf file. 
Check out more here:
[mini_http homepage](http://www.acme.com/software/mini_httpd/)